# Rewrite Rule for default directory index page

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I have a web (magento site) with rewrite engine on, but when i access http://dev.mydomain.com

there will be a error message

**`Forbidden`**

> `"You don't have permission to access /.html on this server."`

there is some rewrite rule is already exists:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

How can i rewrite  http://dev.mydomain.com to  http://dev.mydomain.com/index.php

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php indx.html

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    #Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes +FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## M-Turbo Accelleration (www.artio.net)


    #
    # Rules for storeview 繁
    #

    # store view is choosen by cookie

    # static rewrite - home page

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} store=default;
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !artio_mturbo=.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
    RewriteCond /var/www/directory/var/turbocache/default.html -f
    RewriteRule .* var/turbocache/default.html [L]

    # static rewrite - other pages

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} store=default;
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !artio_mturbo=.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)\.html$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
    RewriteCond /var/www/directory/var/turbocache/default/%1.html -f
    RewriteRule .* var/turbocache/default/%1.html [L]

    # store view is choosen by request_path

    # static rewrite - home page

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !artio_mturbo=.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/default(/|)$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
    RewriteCond /var/www/directory/var/turbocache/default.html -f
    RewriteRule .* var/turbocache/default.html [L]

    # static rewrite - other pages

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !artio_mturbo=.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/default/(.*)\.html$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
    RewriteCond /var/www/directory/var/turbocache/default/%1.html -f
    RewriteRule .* var/turbocache/default/%1.html [L]


    # rules for default storeview

    # static rewrite - home page

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !artio_mturbo=.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
    RewriteCond /var/www/directory/var/turbocache/default.html -f
    RewriteRule .* var/turbocache/default.html [L]

    # static rewrite - other pages

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !artio_mturbo=.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)\.html$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
    RewriteCond /var/www/directory/var/turbocache/default/%1.html -f
    RewriteRule .* var/turbocache/default/%1.html [L]



## End M-Turbo

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    #Order allow,deny
    #Allow from all
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 123.123.123.123
    allow from 123.123.123.123
    allow from 123.123.123.123
    allow from 123.123.123.123
    allow from 123.123.123.123
    allow from 123.123.123.123
    allow from 123.123.123.123
    allow from 123.123.123.123
    allow from 123.123.123.123

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none

#AuthType Basic
#AuthName "restricted area"
#AuthUserFile /var/www/directory/.htpasswd
#require valid-user
```

Comment: the error messages seem to be due to one of the three "# static rewrite - other pages" (%1.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this? ;oP

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_POST} ^dev\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif)|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: I've edited. Do you want everything (http://dev.mydomain.com/?everything or http://dev.mydomain.com/everything/) pointing to http://dev.mydomain.com/index.php or only "http://dev.mydomain.com"?

Comment: i append you answer next to   RewriteRule .* index.php [L], but it is infinite loop

Comment: i just need only when access dev.mydomain.com then rewrite to dev.mydomain.com/index.php

Comment: I've modified HTTP_HOST by REQUEST_URI and specified the condition now.

Comment: REQUEST_URI not work, but i changed it to  
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php  [L]
it works, but the js script not load properly, how do i avoid js/css/jpg are also be rewrite?

Comment: yes, REQUEST_URI only gives the URL part after the domain, so I put back HTTP_POST but ask no .js .css .jpg in URI, does it work? ;oP

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php  [L]

it seems work fine up to now, thx for help